# Regex extract first 3 instances of match from HTML with PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, dom

I have a full html file in PHP variable.. and would like to extract first 3 values in the html  which are formatted as such q?s=XXX OR q?s=XX or q?s=XXXX (where X is a stock symbol).

$html variable contains:

```
<a name='mkt-movers' class='anchor'><\/a><h2 class='Fz-l Fw-200 Mend-4 D-i'>Market Movers<\/h2><\/div><div class=\"bd\">\t<div class=\"dropdown rapid-nf Fw-200 Bdrs\">\n            <form class=\"SelectBox SelectBoxNoBorder\">\n                <div class=\"SelectBox-Pick\">\n                    <span class=\"SelectBox-Text\">U.S. Composite<\/span>\n\t\t    <i class='Icon'>&#xe002;<\/i>\n                <\/div>\n\n                <select data-plugin=\"selectbox\"  class='Start-0' name='selectBox' >\n\t\t    <option value=\"0\" selected=\"selected\" class=\"Selected\">U.S. Composite<\/option><option value=\"1\" >Nasdaq<\/option><option value=\"2\" >NYSE Market<\/option><option value=\"3\" >NYSE<\/option>\n                <\/select>\n                <noscript>\n                    <Btn type=\"submit\" class=\"Hidden\">Select<\/Btn>\n                <\/noscript>\n            <\/form>\n\t<\/div><div class=\"content\"><div class=\"mod-85ac7b2b-640f-323f-a1c1-00b2f4865d18 mod active\"><div id=\"mod_85ac7b2b_640f_323f_a1c1_00b2f4865d18\" class=\"yom-mod yom-app yom-data yfi-table wp yfi-mmovers fin-glass-disabled\">\n\t<a name=\"mkt-movers\" class=\"anchor\"><\/a>\n    <div class=\"hd\">\n        <h2 class=\"Fw-200 Fz-l M-0\"><\/h2>\n    <\/div>\n    <div class=\"bd yom-tabview\">\n            <ul role=\"tablist\" data-plugin='tabpanel' class='FinTabs Mb-10'>\n                <li class=\"Grid-U Mend-8 FinTab-Item Selected rmp-0\" role=\"presentation\">\n                    <a href=\"#mod_85ac7b2b_640f_323f_a1c1_00b2f4865d18-tab1\"  role = \"tab\"  class = \"FinTab-Label no-pjax\"  data-tabpanel-target = \"#mod_85ac7b2b_640f_323f_a1c1_00b2f4865d18-tab1\" >Most Actives<\/a>\n                <\/li>\n                <li class=\"Grid-U Mend-8 FinTab-Item rmp-0\" role=\"presentation\">\n                    <a href=\"#mod_85ac7b2b_640f_323f_a1c1_00b2f4865d18-tab2\"  role = \"tab\"  class = \"FinTab-Label no-pjax\"  data-tabpanel-target = \"#mod_85ac7b2b_640f_323f_a1c1_00b2f4865d18-tab2\" >% Gainers<\/a>\n                <\/li>\n                <li class=\"Grid-U Mend-8 FinTab-Item rmp-0\" role=\"presentation\">\n                    <a href=\"#mod_85ac7b2b_640f_323f_a1c1_00b2f4865d18-tab3\"  role = \"tab\"  class = \"FinTab-Label no-pjax\"  data-tabpanel-target = \"#mod_85ac7b2b_640f_323f_a1c1_00b2f4865d18-tab3\" >% Losers<\/a>\n                <\/li>\n            <\/ul>\n\t<div class=\"yfi-panelcontainer yui3-tabview-panel\">\n            <div role=\"tabpanel\" id=\"mod_85ac7b2b_640f_323f_a1c1_00b2f4865d18-tab1\" class=\" Selected\" data-start=\"0\" data-count=\"10\" data-content=\"mostactive\" >\n        \t<div class=\"original\">\n                \n        <table summary=\"1\" class=\"yom-data col-8 phatable\" >\n          <caption><\/caption>\n          <colgroup><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><\/colgroup>\n          <thead>\n            <tr>\n                <th id=\"table-31-0-0\" class=\"symbol  txt-color\" scope=\"col\"><span>Symbol<\/span><\/th>\n                <th id=\"table-31-0-1\" class=\"name  txt-color\" scope=\"col\"><span>Company Name<\/span><\/th>\n
```

I want to extract the first 3 stock symbols in the large full HTML string above. I.e. output = "BAC", "GE", "MSFT".

Note - stock symbols could be 1, 2, 3 or 4 characters long.

Any ideas to get this would be appreciated - thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, try:

```
if(preg_match_all('~(?<=q\?s=)[-A-Z.]{1,5}~', $source, $out))
{
    // The matches are in [0] (whole pattern)
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($out[0]); echo "</pre>";

    // If you need first 3
    #$out[0] = array_slice($out[0],0,3);
    #echo "<pre>"; print_r($out[0]); echo "</pre>";

    // If you need them unique:
    $out[0] = array_unique($out[0]);
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($out[0]); echo "</pre>";

} else {
    echo "FAIL";
}
```

I changed the pattern a bit, to match stock symbols [like in this list](http://eoddata.com/symbols.aspx) to `~(?<=q\?s=)[-A-Z.]{1,5}~`

- It [looks behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for `q?=`
- If found, matches 1-5 of characters: `A-Z`,`.`, `-`

Comment: Great.. that works very well! Thank you.

Comment: @ChicagoDude Happy it works for you!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
preg_match_all("/q\?s=([A-Za-z\.]{1,5})/",$html,$matches);

for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    if (isset($matches[$i])) {
        echo $i;
    }
}
```

This will match everything in your html string.  You than run a loop from 1 to 3 to get the matches.  Note: the matches captured with the parenthesis will start at `$matches[1]`. `$matches[0]` will contain the text that matched the full pattern.

Here's the documentation about preg_match: https://www.php.net/preg_match

Comment: Need to convert to preg_match_all

Comment: The answer has been updated.

Comment: Thanks - but it didnt work :( The values i get for matches are 1, NULL. Also - i updated my post above with the actual PHP variable contents, if that helps to diagnose the issue.

Comment: @Robbert Escape the `?` else it acts as an [metacharacter](http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/regular-expression/metacharacter-list.php) and would make the `q` optional. So should be `/q\?s=(\w{1,4})/` or even better `/q\?s=([-A-Z.]{1,5})/` as [valid Stock symbols](http://eoddata.com/symbols.aspx) might be `AKO.A` or `AIV-Z`, but this was not the question.

Comment: Tried that.. still returns 1, NULL for some reason. The $html string contents is now in the main question, fyi.

Comment: Your string doesn't have anything like `q?s=`